# SQL Query does not pick up date range start

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- VB.net
- Silverlight 5

The database is a date type with no time component.  In the query I put a time component to ensure proper start and end times.  If I adjust the start date to UTZ time the query works.  If I adjust the start date to yesterday 1 second prior to midnight it does not work.  This indicates to me the database is storing the date as UTZ but that seem impossible.

I have this:

Table

- ID AS int
- dt AS Date

In the table are 2 rows:

```
ID  dt
------------
1   8/1/2014
2   8/2/2014
```

Params:

- `&FromDate = "8/1/2014 00:00:00"`
- `&ToDate = "8/2/2014 23:59:59"`

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE dt >= &FromDate AND dt <= @ToDate
```

Result:

```
ID  dt
------------    
2   8/2/2014
```

The dates are put in the table like this:

MyObject

```
dt as date

myObject.dt = "8/1/2014"

@dt = myObject.dt

INSERT INTO Table (dt) VALUES (@dt)
```

Why do I not get both records with this query?  How do I fix it?

This works:

```
FromDate = Format(FromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy 00:00:00.000"):FromDate = FromDate.AddHours(-5)

ToDate = Format(ToDate.AddDays(1), "MM/dd/yyyy 00:00:00.000"):ToDate = ToDate.AddHours(-5)

sb.Append("AND s.AlarmDate>=@FromDate AND s.AlarmDate<@ToDate ")
```

UPDATE:

A detailed explanation of the environment and the problem.

I have solved this by adjusting the dates as indicated, but I don't like the solution and I don't understand what is causing the problem.

Environment:

Development server is Windows 2003 Server with SQL Server 2008 R2.  Server timezone is CDT.
Production server is Windows Server 2008 also running SQL Server 208 R2, timezone CDT.
Both Development and Production server exhibit the same behavior regarding this problem.

Project is Silverlight 5 website.

Client machine is Windows XP with timezone set to CDT.

To store the record with the date in the database the user initiates a dialog that creates a data object with a date property, this data object is bound to a datepicker.

Lets assume the user select a date of 8/1/2014.

When the user clicks the save button the object is serialized into xml in preperation for posting to a webservice hosted on the server for storage in the database.

The serialization process puts a timestamp in the xml so the xml that arrives at the server has this:

2014-08-01T00:00:00

When the webservice receives this xml it is deserialized into my data object like this:

```
Dim oNote As New DataNote
Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(oNote.GetType)
Dim myStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(xml))
oNote = ser.Deserialize(myStream)
myStream.Close()
```

After the deserialzation of the xml into my object I re-assign the date with the time stamp removed.  I did this to try and fix the problem early on, by using string manipulation and removing the timestamp and assigning only the date portion (as a string) to my object property I am ensuring that if there is a time component it is set to midnight.  This step is probably unnecessary.

The data object property that receives the date is of date type, not datetime, as is the sql table field and the parameter of the stored procedure that updates the database.

Inspection of the databse with SQL Server Management Studio from the client or dev machine shows the date as '2014-08-01' in the database.

So far so good.

To query the date and exhibit the problem:

I am using a telerik report, it hosts a objectdatasouce that uses a class I wrote that returns a list of my objects.  This code is run server side.  The data class uses the SqlConnection provided by ASP.NET, which I assume is ADO to open and query the database.

The query is striaght forward using this clause to locate the date range.

"s.AlarmDate>=@FromDate AND s.AlarmDate<=@ToDate"

If I use a FromDate of #8/1/2014# the query does not find the record.  After experimentation I have discovered that I must subtract 5 hours from the FromDate in order to return the record.

This means that the database is acting as though the data in the database is '7/31/2014 19:00:00".  This is -5 hours from the 'actual' date which happens to be the UTZ offset for CDT (Central Daylight Time).

It could also mean that my FromDate is 5 hours ahead.  This makes even less sense to me so I am dismissing it.

That's it.  There are no other layers involved, its as simple as that.

Comment: I believe I figured out what is going on.  I purposely strip the time component from the date before I insert it in the table, the server must interpret that as UTZ, so even though I see 8/1/2014 somewhere along the way I get 7/31/2014 19:00:00.000, which is the servers -5 UTZ offset (CDT). If I adjust my start and end dates by the server offset of -5 it all works.  I don't like it.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by *"strip the time component from the date before I insert it in the table"*? I suspect you are not doing this correctly, resulting in the persistent offset you see.

Comment: Also, do you have some other software in between your UI and SQL Server? Like ADO or ODBC that might be converting back and forth between DATE and DATETIME using the local timezone?

Comment: OK - it gets even stranger.  I manually added a record with 7/31/2014 using VS2010 server explorer.  my 'fixed' query with -5 offset caught the 7/31/2014 date.  I then programmatically added a record as a user would with a 7/31/2014 date, now the query does not pick up either 7/31/2014 date (which is correct and what I want, but why????)

Comment: Please explain your software environment in more detail. You have some intermediate software performing inconsistent conversion between local and UTC timezone, and it is impossible to figure out how and why without very specific details about how yor date values are going back and forth.

Comment: By stripping off the time I mean as I showed in the example, the data arrives as xml with a time component, I remove it and only assign the date portion as a string to my object property (date type) which is used to set the sql param.  The only in between process is my data object, the code that runs the query is server side and it populates a list of my objects which is then used in a telerik report (but the error occurs prior to the report)

Comment: Now it is the objectdatasource of the telerik report that cals my class to query the data, but I can't see how that would matter.  I'm still leaning to the theory that the sql server is storing the date as 8/1/2014T-5, perhaps not because of sql server, but then the asp.net webservice responsible for updating the database record.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
&FromDate = "8/1/2014 00:00:00"
&ToDate = "8/3/2014 00:00:00"
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE dt >= &FromDate AND dt < @ToDate
```

Note the very important changes to the inequality and to the ToDate value. There is an issue in SQL Server with the resolution of times just before and just after the hour, requiring the use of this technique to get correct reproducible results.  In practice it is impossible to reliably set a datetime value to *just before* a date change.

Also, it is very highly recommended that you either use the format 'yyyymmdd' for date strings being implicitly converted to dates (or dtetimes), or explicitly select a specific format [using the CONVERT function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx)

**Update** - after comments from OP above.

Always use the most specific possible datatype for parameters to stored procedures. Change the datatype of the date parameter in your stored procedure to DATE, so that you are in control of the conversion to/from character.

Comment: Start date is the problem, not end date, though I expect the issue lies in both.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, the database type is date, the stored procedure was datetime, I changed it to date but still have the same issue, but yes they should all match.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the time component of the row w/ the 8/2 date.

For instance if it were:

```
insert into tbl values (2, '08/02/2014 23:59:59.999');
```

That row would not come back in your query (notice the .999)
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dc42/1/0

But if the row were:

```
insert into tbl values (2, '08/02/2014 23:59:59');
```

That row would come back (no .999) -
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed49b/1/0

Try changing the parameter to the following value (with nnn seconds):

```
select *
from tbl 
where dt >= '8/1/2014 00:00:00' and dt <= '8/2/2014 23:59:59.999'
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dc42/3/0

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Alternatively if you can change the condition to 'less than' rather than <= you could could do < the third at 0 hours.

Comment: I'm getting the end date, its the start date that is not being returned. if I set the start date to '7/31/2014 23:59:59" it still does not work.  However '7/31/2014 19:59:59" does work. That's -4 which is my UTZ offset.  I will experiment with different hours to see if I can figure out how far off the time is, but looking in the db the data is '8/1/2014' (!)

Comment: above s/b -5, not -4.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a detailed explanation of the environment and the problem.

I have solved this by adjusting the dates as indicated, but I don't like the solution and I don't understand what is causing the problem.

Environment:

Development server is Windows 2003 Server with SQL Server 2008 R2.  Server timezone is CDT.
Production server is Windows Server 2008 also running SQL Server 208 R2, timezone CDT.
Both Development and Production server exhibit the same behavior regarding this problem.

Project is Silverlight 5 website.

Client machine is Windows XP with timezone set to CDT.

To store the record with the date in the database the user initiates a dialog that creates a data object with a date property, this data object is bound to a datepicker.

Lets assume the user select a date of 8/1/2014.

When the user clicks the save button the object is serialized into xml in preperation for posting to a webservice hosted on the server for storage in the database.

The serialization process puts a timestamp in the xml so the xml that arrives at the server has this:

2014-08-01T00:00:00

When the webservice receives this xml it is deserialized into my data object like this:

```
Dim oNote As New DataNote
Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(oNote.GetType)
Dim myStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(xml))
oNote = ser.Deserialize(myStream)
myStream.Close()
```

After the deserialzation of the xml into my object I re-assign the date with the time stamp removed.  I did this to try and fix the problem early on, by using string manipulation and removing the timestamp and assigning only the date portion (as a string) to my object property I am ensuring that if there is a time component it is set to midnight.  This step is probably unnecessary.

The data object property that receives the date is of date type, not datetime, as is the sql table field and the parameter of the stored procedure that updates the database.

Inspection of the databse with SQL Server Management Studio from the client or dev machine shows the date as '2014-08-01' in the database.

So far so good.

To query the date and exhibit the problem:

I am using a telerik report, it hosts a objectdatasouce that uses a class I wrote that returns a list of my objects.  This code is run server side.  The data class uses the SqlConnection provided by ASP.NET, which I assume is ADO to open and query the database.

The query is striaght forward using this clause to locate the date range.

"s.AlarmDate>=@FromDate AND s.AlarmDate<=@ToDate"

If I use a FromDate of #8/1/2014# the query does not find the record.  After experimentation I have discovered that I must subtract 5 hours from the FromDate in order to return the record.

This means that the database is acting as though the data in the database is '7/31/2014 19:00:00".  This is -5 hours from the 'actual' date which happens to be the UTZ offset for CDT (Central Daylight Time).

It could also mean that my FromDate is 5 hours ahead.  This makes even less sense to me so I am dismissing it.

That's it.  There are no other layers involved, its as simple as that.

Comment: Is it possible there is a setting in sql server that tell it to store dates as UTZ?

Comment: This is interesting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/03/31/the-death-of-datetime.aspx

Comment: I had dismissed the case where my FromDate and ToDate params were 5 hours ahead - but if I query with sql mgmt studio with a date range of 8/1/2014 it works, but my code query returns dates of 8/1 and 8/2, it looks like it must be the FromDate and ToDate param that are off.  If I subtract 5 hours from the params the query works as expected and matches the mgmt studio results.

Comment: You should have edited the question instead of this, as it stand it will be probably flagged as "Very Low Quality" or "Not an answer"